# how to call intent from asynctask which is in baseadapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I am creating buttons in grid which is using `BaseAdapter`. I need to connect to server when button is clicked and depending on the result from db i am deciding the next event to be carried out.

So I have written the `AsyncTask` in **custombaseadapter** and calling it in onclick event of button. there I need to start new activity using intents.

I tried using the same context which I am using in baseadapter but it crashes the app.

Here is the `postExecute()` method in which I am calling the intent:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {

    try {

        //TableLayout tll12=(TableLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ordertab1);
        // convert json string to json array
        JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);

        JSONObject jsonO = aJson.getJSONObject(0);
        tabres=jsonO.getString("MSG");

        if(tabres.equals("No")){
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();                    
            bundle.putString("username",Table_no.username);                                                 
            Intent myint=new Intent(mContext,Take_order.class);
            myint.putExtras(bundle);
            mContext.startActivity(myint);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Bill Already Generated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        msg = "Invalid response";
    }
}
```

I have declared this mContext in baseadapter and initialising it in its constructor.

this is the logcat

```
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2876)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.example.androiddbconnection.CustomGridViewAdapter$tableasync.onPostExecute(CustomGridViewAdapter.java:266)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.example.androiddbconnection.CustomGridViewAdapter$tableasync.onPostExecute(CustomGridViewAdapter.java:1)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-31 12:32:43.380: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Intent myint=new Intent(activityname.this,Take_order.class);

Comment: Do you initialized mContext properly?

Comment: @Digvesh I am doing this in baseadapter so activityname.this is not possible

Comment: @Raghunandan line 266 is   Intent myint=new Intent(mContext,Take_order.class);

Comment: @Fahim Ahmed Yes I am using the same mContext in baseadapter getview method and its working properly.

Comment: yes. How should I initialise it and where. I am already using same mContext in getview

Comment: can you post some more code here to see how it flow?

Comment: Use `YourActivity.this` instead of `mContext` @AnkitaDeshmukh

Comment: @AnkitaDeshmukh Try to print `Table_no.username` in Log.